# Ruby - traverse through nokogiri element

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an html like this:

```
...
<table>
<tbody>
    ...
    <tr>
    <th> head </th>
    <td> td1 text<td>
    <td> td2 text<td>
    ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
</tfoot>
</table>

...
```

I'm using Nokogiri with ruby. I want traverse through each row and get the text of th and corresponding td into an hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require "nokogiri"

#Parses your HTML input
html_data = "...stripped HTML markup code..." 
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML html_data

#Iterates over each row in your table
#Note that you may need to clarify the CSS selector below
result = html_doc.css("table tr").inject({}) do |all, row|

  #Modify if you need to collect only the first td, for example
  all[row.css("th").text] = row.css("td").text

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't run this code, so I'm not absolutely sure but the overall idea should be right:

```
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<html> ... </html>")
result = []
html_doc.xpath("//tr").each do |tr|
  hash = {}
  tr.children.each do |node|
    hash[node.node_name] = node.content
  end
  result << hash
end
puts result.inspect
```

See the docs for more info: http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html

Comment: I'm getting some empty nodes as child. How I can skip those?

Comment: tr.css("th") and tr.css("td") will do this.
thank you Evgeny.